# MYSQL remove word from a column in a table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and want to go through the entire wp_posts database using MYSQL to remove the word "on" from the slugs.

I've tried these two lines;

```
update wp_posts set post_name = replace(post_name, '%on-%', '') where post_type = "post";

select *, replace(post_name, '%on-%', '') from wp_posts where post_type = "post";
```

They dont remove the word 'on' from things such as "12th-annual-helmets-on-kids-campaign"

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_name, 'on-', '') where post_type = "post";
```

and omit the `%`.

Comment: Worked :) You're my hero kind sir!